# shell script to load xml file into mysql database

Tags: xml, shell

I have an xml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<table name="abc">
<row>
<field name="year">2015</field>
<field name="copyright">Various</field>
<field name="review">Various</field>
</row>
<field name="year">2015</field>
<field name="copyright">Various</field>
<field name="review">Various</field>
<row>
<field name="year">2015</field>
<field name="copyright"/>
<field name="review"/>
</row>
</table>
```

The command for loading this xml file into mysql database is :

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/home/first.xml' INTO TABLE abc;
```

But this command is showing fields in database having proper closing tags.
In the third row copyright and review are having closing tags as `/>` So its showing entire row values as NULL even if `year` is having value as `2015`. How this issue can be resolved any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two documents. You should use both.

1. [Using mysql in bash script](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/using-mysql-in-shell-scripts/)
2. [Load xml into MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)

First connect to mysql from bash script and then run load xml command in that batch.

Comment: I connected to db already. i just showed part of my shell script where its not working properly.

Comment: Only prb is if my closing tag is "/>" then its giving NULL for all the fields

Answer (score 0):

Using Java i replaced `/>` with `></field>`.
So now the values are properly getting entered in db